# How to add an empty link in question

Tags: support

I want to add an empty link in question so I present a link like text, but won't create any response

I want to ask in my question about a problem with invalid link

**EDIT**

I want to display the below as text:

[image: 404 link]

Comment: Put it in a Stack Snippet maybe? If this is a web development question.

Comment: @BoltClock I want to ask a question in stackoverflow containing an empty link

Comment: Why? What are you trying to illustrate with that fake link?

Comment: Format it as a code

Comment: @BoltClock I want to how issue in code create an empty link

Comment: Use backticks or code block for this if you are showing a url format

Comment: @SurajRao I want to show the the link that created isn't linking to nowhere

Comment: Why not just put the markup in a code block? `<a>This is an empty link</a>` You only need to present the code problematic code, no need to render it in the question directly.

Comment: @user7294900 do you have a scenario where this is used? I am unable to understand your issue

Comment: Why is it so important for the text to have the appearance of a link?

Comment: @SurajRao I want to show the java doc link is not working (but shown as a link)

Comment: You can just say that the link is not working. I don't think there is a need to illustrate that.

Comment: Again, just show the markup. If you need to reproduce the issue, just use a stack snippet.

Comment: @yivi I've edit the question

Comment: @BoltClock should I add the image I added in edit instead? It's not clear

Comment: I guess it's just an accident. But that tiny screenshot in an already hard to understand question is hilarious.

Comment: The close reason should be "unclear **why** you're asking..."

Comment: Anyway, meta-XY problem, I guess. You want to ask a question about a link doesn't work, and try to reproduce it on the SE post in its non-working format. SE posts are not supposed to display arbitrary HTML code. (if I understand the question correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, you can't. The editor / markdown parser removes any links that don't actually have an url in it:

`<a href="#">This is an empty link</a>` renders as:

This is an empty link

Comment: can I simulate a link ? (under line and blue color)

Comment: No, you can't style a question or answer's contents.